# AngularJS : Use of ng-if and ng-class combination

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angular-ng-if

I have a table like this :

```
<tr>
        <th scope="row">QUANTITÉ PRODUITE</th>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][0][0]}}</td>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][0][1]}}</td>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][0][2]}}</td>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][0][3]}}</td>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][0][4]}}</td>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][0][5]}}</td>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][0][6]}}</td>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][0][7]}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">OBJECTIF QUANTITÉ</th>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][2][0]}}</td>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][2][1]}}</td>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][2][2]}}</td>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][2][3]}}</td>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][2][4]}}</td>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][2][5]}}</td>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][2][6]}}</td>
        <td>{{hoursValues[0][2][7]}}</td>
      </tr>
```

I want to compare each column of a row with the other corresponding column, for example : hoursValues[0][0][0] && hoursValues[0][2][0] and according to this comparison, I want to apply the classes.
I mean, if hoursValues[0][0][0] > hoursValues[0][2][0], I want to display the result in green else red.

Can anyone help me ? What should I write in my controller ?

Comment: read the documentation for ng-class. It's what you need. Forget about ng-if in this case

Comment: yes thank you, i used only ng-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in each td just do this

```
<td ng-class="{true:'green', false:'red'}[hoursValues[0][0][0] > hoursValues[0][2][0]]">
```

obvius just change each column with corresponding one.
next td

```
<td ng-class="{true:'green', false:'red'}[hoursValues[0][0][1] > hoursValues[0][2][1]]">
```